# Prevent main while loop from blocking while waiting on other threads to finish : python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have while loop running in main and it is creating and starting threads. But until these threads finishes it's task, it blocks the while loop from creating other threads. Any Help is appreciated. I have tried using condition but it dint work.

My Code :

```
    def main():
         while True:
           result = DoTaskBatch()


    def DoTaskBatch():
         for task in tasks:
            task_thread = TaskThread(task)
            task_thread.start()

 class TaskThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.task = task
       self.status = TASK_PASS

    def run(self):
       task = self.task
       processed_image_name = DoTask(task)
```

Comment: You don't need to do this, your code will only be called when there is a task in the queue; you don't need to manage your workers and continuously check if there are things in the queue for you to work on. The broker takes care of this for you.

Comment: This is the code I am following from Google's own sample project. Even though while loop is not a problem. The problem is if one of my thread   is taking too long to process 1 task then atleast the while loop should not get blocked and keep leasing the task from task the queue(if there are any) .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should fix your indentation for you `while` and `for` loops. Second of all why not start the threads before the `while` loop. I don't see why you would want to do in the `while` loop

Comment: Sorry about that.I fixed the indentation. I need while loop because it continuously checks task in a Google App Engine task queue and lease it and create threads accordingly. So it has to be inside while loop.

Comment: You do realize that you will continue to create threads over and over again right ?

Comment: Yes.This is how it works..whenever user makes request , Task Queue gets the task and this while loop(which keeps checking task in a task queue) lease the task and then creates the Thread. So it wont continuously creating threads, only when needed.

Comment: ok so there's a queue involved ? You are not showing that in the code you posted. You should post the actual code.

Comment: @jramirez Your answer should really be a comment on the question as you are asking for clarifications.

Comment: @jramirez There is no literal queue that I am creating anywhere in my code. This queue is Google App Engine queue that my while loop keeps on checking.